# Why does find_element by XPATH give too many web elements while iterating through a datepicker?

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

> Blockquote

I am working on a project where I need to scrape data from a graph that shows the data for 1 day. For example: I want to get al the data for 2017 so I have to enter a new date in the datepicker 365 times. The problem is that although I am very specific in my XPATH call, the script finds way to many webelements. Many of which are not even compliant to my restrictions in my XPATH. This only happens some way into the loop and every loop the script finds more and more web elements.

The code that I am using:

```html
Date_vec = pd.date_range(start="2017-01-01",end="2021-2-28")

DatePicker = web.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/input')

month_prev = 0
year_prev = 0

for i in Date_vec:
    DatePicker = web.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/input')
    DatePicker.click()
    if i.year != year_prev:
        # Year_button = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@onclick = 'basicDatePicker.ehYearSelectorClick(this)']")
        Year_button = web.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//span[@onclick = 'basicDatePicker.ehYearSelectorClick(this)']")
        Year_button[-1].click()
        
        Year_choice = web.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[normalize-space(text()) ='"+ str(i.year)  + "']")
        Year_choice[-1].click()
        

    elif i.month != month_prev:
        Month_button = web.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@onclick = 'basicDatePicker.ehMonthSelectorClick(this)']")
        Month_button[-1].click()
        Month_choice = web.find_elements_by_class_name('bdpMonthItem')
        Month_choice[i.month-1].click()
    
    Day_button = web.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[normalize-space(text()) ='"+ str(i.day)  + "' and contains(@class, 'bdpDay')]")
    Day_button[-1].click()

    

    
    time.sleep(3)
    month_prev = i.month
    year_prev = i.year
```

For example, the problem arises at the line below:

```
Day_button = web.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[normalize-space(text()) ='"+ str(i.day)  + "' and contains(@class, 'bdpDay')]")
```

This line returns 4 elements of which 2 don't have any text in them. I checked this with the following line.

```
test1 = [i.text for i in Day_button]
```

So my question basically is: Why does the line code return 4 elements of which two don't have text while I explicitly tell it to have the current day as text. Any help is appreciated.

edit: for clarity, I added a snip from the datepicker in question:
[image: snip from the datepicker]

Comment: Are there two datepickers available on the page? Maybe each provides two elements with desired text?

Comment: There is only one, I suspect it finds elements from previous loops as the number of elements is getting larger by one each time. For example, after changing the date 10 times, I will find 10 elements for the with the line for "Day button = ...". Of these 10, only 1 has the text corresponding to the day I want. Fairly strange...

Comment: It's possible that DOM still contains orphan branches. To help you please provide the absolute path of one of these  datepicker's elements - one for corresponding and one for odd one. The whole HTML would help,  attach the link to the page if it's public one

Comment: If I use test = [i.get_attribute('xpath') for i in Day_button] it returns a list with nonetype objects. The working element is still in that list, I checked it by using .click(). The page is not public sadly... Any idea to obtain the XPATH in another way for you to check your hypothesis?